# TIdTCPConnection.ReadFromStackと同等の機能はIndy10にはありますか？

Tags: delphi

Indy9で書かれたプログラム

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
----------(中略)---------------------------------------
    TIdTCPServerConnection * con = AThread->Connection;
----------(中略)---------------------------------------
       int iExpectedLen = 0, iStackBufSize=0;
----------(中略)---------------------------------------
       iStackBufSize = con->ReadFromStack(true,5000,true);
----------(中略)---------------------------------------
}
```

このプログラムをIndy10のプログラムに移行したいのですが、ReadFromStackというのをIndy10の取説でキーワード検索しても出てこないのですが、同等の機能というものはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

こんな記事があるので：
[Upgrade Indy9 to Indy10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2027579/9014308)
質問

> I want to upgrade my application from Indy 9 to 10 with Delphi 2007. There is a lot of issues in this, I have read the indy doc about changes but I still need advise. This won't compile as ReadString is not found.
>
> ```
> vCmdHead := FTCPClient.ReadString(16);
> ```
>
> where FTCPClient is of type TIdTCPClient. vCmdHead is a structure that contains a command as a string. What method could I use instead ?

回答

> ```
>   {$IFDEF INDY10}
>   ALine := IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadString(16);
>   {$ELSE}
>   Aline := IdTCPClient.ReadString(16);
>   {$ENDIF}
> ```
>
> Something like this

他にこんな記事も：
[Upgrading Delphi 7 Indy 9 app to Indy 10 (II)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40195248/9014308)

---

それの類推でこれあたりが該当しそうです。
[TIdIOHandlerStack Class](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21MEMBEROVERVIEW_TIdIOHandlerStack.html)
[TIdIOHandlerStack Members](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21MEMBEROVERVIEW_TIdIOHandlerStack.html)
[TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes Method](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html)

[TIdTCPConnection Class](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection.html)
[TIdTCPConnection Members](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection.html)
[TIdTCPConnection.CreateIOHandler Method](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection_CreateIOHandler@TIdIOHandlerClass.html)
[TIdTCPConnection.IOHandler Property](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection_IOHandler.html)
[TIdTCPConnection.ManagedIOHandler Property](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPConnection_ManagedIOHandler.html)

実際に関係するのか、どのように使えば良いか等は調べてみてください。

Indy9の該当メソッドの記事はこちら。
[TIdTCPConnection.ReadFromStack](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007828.html#0029)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。

Comment: `iStackBufSize = con->ReadFromStack(true,5000,true); `

このコードの iStackBufSizeっていう意味を調べていくと、


` if(iStackBufSize < iExpectedLen)
   {
    AContext->Data = NULL;
    AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
    ((TIdYarnOfThread*)(AContext->Yarn))->Thread->Terminate();


   }`
という感じでiExpectedLen（1204バイト？）という受信されるはずのパケットの大きさをここでチェックして、そうでなかったらエラーとして判定して切断するみたいなことをやってるみたいです。

Comment: このコードの iStackBufSizeっていう意味を調べていくと、


`if(iStackBufSize < iExpectedLen)
   {
    AContext->Data = NULL;
    AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
    ((TIdYarnOfThread*)(AContext->Yarn))->Thread->Terminate();


   }`
という感じでiExpectedLen（1204バイト？）という受信されるはずのパケットの大きさをここでチェックして、そうでなかったらエラーとして判定して切断するみたいなことをやってるみたいです。

Comment: `iStackBufSize = con->IOHandler->ReadByte();`
とりあえず、これでやってみようと思います。

Comment: `iStackBufSize = con->IOHandler->RecvBufferSize;`何となくこれでもいいのかなという感じもしてます（＾＾；　とりあえずデバッグしてみます。